# Access Centos Apache Server (Hosted in Parallels 10) From Mac OSX

Tags: macos, apache, centos, parallels

I am testing some software on a Centos 6 system running in Parallels 10, based on my Mac - i.e. the Mac is the host, Centos 6 is the client.

I have Apache installed and working on the guest, however, for testing purposes:

1. I would like to access the Centos Apache server from the Mac
2. I would also like other computers on the network access the Centos Apache

Comment: Decided to install Centova on an old PC and set up a webserver

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are running the Parallells virtual machine in bridging mode or not. If you do it will get it's own ip in the network (i.e 192.168.x.x).

If you don't use it in bridging it can be accessed via a virtual network within Parallells (i.e. 10.211.55.x). This network give your Mac (and other Parallells virtual machines) access to each other.

You can also forward traffic from your Mac's network ip to your Parallells machine. This will forward port 80:

```
sudo ssh -g -L80:localhost:80 10.211.55.x
```

Make sure your firewall lets through traffic on the right ports.

```
iptables -L
```

Or for testing, just turn it off...

```
service iptables stop
```

Comment: Hi, I've got it up and running now. Apache works on port 80, however, I have another service running on port 8000. This works fine on the client (i.e. localhost:8000), however, I get connection refused when trying this from my host (http://192.168.1.45:8000)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you stopped iptables?

Are you sure your applicationsa are listening on the ports you think you are? What is the output of?

     netstat --listen

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

Two things I had to do here

1) Close down the IP tables service (or open the relevant ports, both worked in this case).

2) In my software instance that was running on port 8000, I had to set it to bind to port 0.0.0.0 rather than local host, this allowed external sources to connect.